# PHP regex backreference glitch

Tags: php, regex, backreference

Wanting to parse custom moderator's tags in mybb posts.

> [mod="Nomad"]Curabitur eu ultricies nunc[/mod].
>   Donec et luctus nisi, a imperdiet ipsum.
>   [mod="Nomad"]Morbi feugiat tellus lectus, a auctor ligula elementum ac[/mod].

The following php regex matches nothing :

```
#\[mod=(['\"])(.*?)\1](.*?)\[/mod]#
```

Although this one works (note the added g in the backref)

```
#\[mod=(['\"])(.*?)\g1](.*?)\[/mod]#
```

As well as this one (using named subpatterns seems a bit overkill)

```
#\[mod=(?P<quot>['\"])(.*?)(?P=quot)](.*?)\[/mod]#
```

edit: This regex is for getting the part inside [mod][/mod] so that I can style it or hide it away from common users.

Is it a know glitch or I am missing something?

Thanks

Comment: How are you quoting the regexp? In double quotes, `\1` is an octal character, so `preg_match()` won't see the backslash. Use single quotes instead to keep the literal backslash.

Comment: shouldn't you also escape your trailing `\[/mod\]`?

Comment: @DaveGoten `]` doesn't have any special meaning if it's not after `[`, so it doesn't need to be escaped by itself.

Comment: @Barmar hmm guess I'm too strict on myself then :)

Comment: @Barmar that was the problem, I changed for single quotes and it worked. Thanks !

Comment: The documentation of backreferences even says that this is the reason `\g` was added

Answer (score 0):

Here you have what you probably want:

```
\[mod=(['"])(.*?)\1\](.*?)\[\/mod\]
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/zB5bX3/2

Comment: Where is your backreference?

Comment: Edited so you can have both `'` and `"`.